# VSCode change keybindings global

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I use Ctrl+Shift to change keyboard layout in Linux. And all VSCode "Ctrl+Shift+..." keyboard shortcuts don't work. How can I change these keyboard shortcuts to "meta+Shift" at once. It is desirable that extensions installed after this also use this replacement. Or tell me in which file (location) on Linux the global hotkey settings for 1.76.2 are registered

An attempt to use the user's keybinding.json failed because it is empty. And I don’t want to drag the entire global keybinding.json file into it

Comment: you can't replace a modifier key for a different one, add the modified key bindings in the `keybindings.json` file, I don't think you use all the `Ctrl+Shift` default key bindings

Comment: easier to change the `change keyboard layout` key

Answer (score 0):

- execute command: **Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)**
- copy all content until the comments
- paste it in the `keybindings.json` file
- search-replace `ctrl+shift` to `meta+shift`